# Rails DISTINCT query doesn't work when doing iteration

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I want to show the last visited location for a user. As a consideration, user may visit the location multiple times, so I just want to show the location by the last time the `location_id` shows up in running activities. 
I use rails query with this code

```
runnings = @current_user.
  runnings.
  where(with_friend: true).
  order('created_at DESC').
  distinct('location_id').
  select([:location_id, :created_at])
```

It works perfectly. It doesn't show the same running activities twice as this

```
#<Running id: nil, created_at: "2018-02-09 12:51:48", location_id: 10>
```

And I also can get the Location based on `location_id` as this

```
locations = Location.where('id in (:location_ids)', location_ids: runnings.map {|running| running.location_id})
```

By the way I have 21 dummy runnings data and the locations shows only 10, that's what I expected.
But when I tried to get the created_at attributes from runnings with this code

```
runnings.map {|running| running.created_at.to_i}
```

It shows 21 data again, and I can't count it unless I change it to array or to json which shows 21 data also.
What's wrong with my code? Could you help me resolve it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you show the generated SQL from your query?

Comment: locationids.length gives you 21?  i suspect with_friend: true is filtering the records

Answer (score 0):

Distinct applies to all selected columns, not just `location_id` as you expected. You can use `group` to resolve your problem:

```
runnings = @current_user.
  runnings.
  where(with_friend: true).
  select('MAX(created_at), location_id').
  group(:location_id, :created_at)
```

Comment: forgot `.` after select call

Comment: it works, but created_at doesn't seem want to distinct itself with .distinct(:location_id)

Comment: How many `runnings` returns in your query? Is the generated query distinct just one `location_id`?